# mysql update query is not running

Tags: php, mysql, sql

MySQL update query is not working on the php based webpage also not showing any MySQL error but when copy the query and run it in SQL it works fine.

Here is my code:

```
$query = "UPDATE table_name SET page_name = '".$page_name."' WHERE ip = '".$ip."'";
$update = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

please if anyone sees anything wrong in the code please let me know.

Comment: not working? is that record not being updated?

Comment: Your code is not protected to mysql injection, but as @vai said, in this part of your code is nothing bad with PHP syntax. Maybe your account don't have UPDATE access?

Comment: let say $page_name = 'login.php' but when the query execute the mysql table update with a value 'index.php' instead of 'login.php' i do not understand why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

You should try this syntax instead:

```
$query = "UPDATE table_name SET page_name = '$page_name' WHERE ip = '$ip'";
$update = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
```

Please note that `mysql_*` methods are deprecated and you should use `mysqli_*` methods instead.

Comment: Sorry, but your code is not better as his. Maybe worse with this format without separating variables and strings.

Comment: let say $page_name = 'login.php' but when the query execute the mysql table update with a value 'index.php' instead of 'login.php' i do not understand why this is happening

Comment: @Vikrant , may be you define global $page_name in any file or current page as $page_name, so its override $page_name. so it all time take index.php not login.php

Comment: @chirag no global variable i find $page_name in entire files i did not found any other variable name $page_name

Comment: I also have other update query in different part of the site and they all are updating fine, i do not understand why only this one is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Demo Code : Its Work Fine for me.Please Use it.

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';

$dbuser = 'root';

$dbpass = '';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if(! $conn )

{

  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

}

$page = 'Hello';

$ip = '102.101.22.23';

$sql = "UPDATE `pages`
        SET `pagename` = '".$page."'
        WHERE `ip` = '".$ip."'";

/* OR use $sql = "UPDATE pages SET pagename= '".$page."' WHERE ip='".$ip."'"; */

mysql_select_db('demo');

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if(! $retval )

{

  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());

}

echo "Updated data successfully\n";

mysql_close($conn);
```